# Android ListActivity new intent issue (adding space)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

How to open a new intent when there are spaces within the array (such as "Hello World") The class I'm trying to access is called startingPoint.

It gives me an error as there cannot be any spaces within the  -> android:name=""

Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance

Root.java

```
public class Root extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = { "Hello World", "Another Item", "Email"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Root.this,
            R.layout.root, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String MENU_CHOICE = classes[position];
    try {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("se.hello.visboken." + MENU_CHOICE);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Root.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My manifest looks like this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Root"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="se.hello.visboken.ROOT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".startingPoint"
        android:label="Hello World" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="se.hello.visboken.startingPoint" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the Activity you need to launch is `startingPoint`, **not** `Hello World`. *Hello World* is the title of that activity.

---

**Update:**

Create another string array of same size (must) but contains classes' names inside, not titles.

```
String tmp[] = { "startingPoint", "anotherClass1", "anotherClass2"};
```

and in *onListItemClick*, read it as below:

```
String MENU_CHOICE = tmp[position];
```

Comment: I still want the strings in the listactivity to be the ones presented on the screen and I want to fire the intent that is called in the manifest.

Comment: then try replacing **Hello World** with **startingPoint** in `String classes[]`

Comment: If I do that Hello World will not be shown as a listitem in the listactivity on the actual phone, I still want it to say "Hello World" there but I cannot launch an activity if it has spaces in it. Sorry if I were unclear at first.

Comment: you simply cant launch an activity with space in its name. any how, see my updated answer.